# Is there any item in a collection that is equal to a specific string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method which returns a list of strings. I want to check if a certain string is equal to any item from that list.

```
bool isExist = (GetData().Any().Equals(specificString)) ? true : false;
```

this returns false always. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you should probably write it like:

```
bool isExist = GetData().Any(x => x == specificString);
```

What you where writing was:

```
bool temp1 = GetData().Any();
```

that is `true` if `GetData()` has any one record, `false` otherwise

and then

```
bool isExist = temp1.Equals(specificString).
```

Clearly `true`/`false` are always different from `specificString`